# ctmm.fit function throws an error 'cannot allocate memory of size'

Tags: r

I use the ctmm package to calculate `AKDE` in `R`. The data consists locations of camera trap locations that have been visited by elephant individuals. I remove instances where the individual has repeatedly visited the same camera trap, so the dataset has only unique camera traps visited.

This is the code that I run:

```
ele_move = as.telemetry(eleconsec_df, timezone = "UTC)
summary_list = lapply(ele_move, function(x){
 guess = ctmm.guess(x, interactive = F)
 fit = ctmm.fit(x, guess)
 ud = akde(x, fit)
 as.data.frame(summary(ud)$CI)
}
```

The lapply function throws gives the following warnings and an error:
`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 519771.5 Gb`

In addition: Warning messages:

```
1. In cov.loglike(hess, grad) :
 MLE is near a boundary or optimizer failed
2. In ctmm.fit(x, guess) :
 pREML failure: indefinite ML Hessian or divergent REML gradient
3. In cov.loglike(DIFF$hessian, grad) :
```

I tried running the `akde` functions separately for each individual. It runs completely with a couple of warnings for a few, and throws the `cannot allocate vector of size` error for the others.

Strangely, when I used a larger `dataframe` that has duplicate locations of individuals across consecutive days, the `lapply` function runs without an error! I may need to remove locations where individuals visit the same camera trap location over consecutive days, though, because the `lower CI estimate of AKDE` returned for one individual was 0.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this vignette: https://ctmm-initiative.github.io/ctmm/reference/ctmm.fit.html , I figured I should have used 'ctmm.select' instead of 'ctmm.fit', since I was getting the warning "MLE is near a boundary or optim() failed" (see the section on Warnings in the vignette.